# Libgdx - Objects are rendered only on click

Tags: java, android, android-studio, mobile, libgdx

I'm developing a game and in the render function I have:
(Square extends Sprite)

```
 @Override
    public void render(float delta) {
        Gdx.gl.glClearColor(0, 0, 0, 0);
        Gdx.gl.glClear(GL20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
        batch.begin();
        backgroundSprite.draw(batch);

        endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if((endTime-startTime) > 1000) {
            squareList.add(squarePositionFactory.getSquare());
            for(Square square : squareList) {
                square.setSize(80, 80);
                square.draw(batch);
                square.updatePosition(square.posX, square.posY + 100);
                startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                Gdx.app.log("[Playing time]", square.toString());
            }
        }
        batch.end();

        stage.act(Gdx.graphics.getDeltaTime());
        stage.draw();
    }
```

The problem is the render method only works when I click repeatdly on the screen so the images are displayed blinking. How can I fix this? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may find [this page](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Continuous-&-non-continuous-rendering) useful.

Answer (score 0):

you haven't add the actor to the stage.

```
   stage.addActor("your actor");
   stage.draw();
```